# glibc (libc.so) だけを使ったアプリケーションは glibc を使っていることを明記する必要があるのか？

Tags: ライセンス, gpl

以下の条件を満たすアプリケーションで、glibc の LGPL2 ライセンスに沿った形で製品をリリースするには、何をしたらよいのか、教えてください。

- 対象アプリケーションが libc.so を実行時に使う、動的リンクで作成されていること。（よって LGPL2 6b を満たす）
- アプリケーションは glibc が提供するライブラリしか使っていない。（極端な話、printf だけ。と仮定してください）
- アプリケーション自体は (L)GPL では無いライセンス。（簡単に、商用アプリケーションとします）
- アプリケーション自身のライセンスとして、リバースエジニアリングを許す。(LGPL2 6)

私は、glibc が LGPL 2 ライセンスであるのだから、さらに

> あなたは著作物のそれぞれのコピーに、『ライブラリ』がその著作物の中で用いられていることと、その利用はこのライセンスで保護されていることを述べたはっきりとした告知を載せねばならない。また、あなたはこのライセンスのコピーを一部提供しなければならない。もし著作物が実行時に著作権表示を表示するならば、あなたはその中に『ライブラリ』の著作権表示を含めなければならず、更にユーザにこのライセンスのコピーの在処を示す参照文も含めなければならない。

をしなければいけないと考えています。
が、Mozila/FireFox も LibraOffice も、そのライセンス一覧に glibc がありません。
info-zip の zip は objdump を見る限り glibc だけを動的にリンクしていますが、やはりライセンス表記に glibc に対する言及がありません。

最初は GCCランタイム・ライブラリ例外 によって (L)GPL では無くなっているのかと思いましたが glibc が GCC RLE に含まれているという記述を見つけることは出来ませんでした。

glibc だけ、何か特別なライセンスになっているのでしょうか？

Comment: glibcを使っていることを含めればいいのでは？LGPLv2でダイナミックリンクならアプリのソースコードを開示する必要はないはず。細かいことを言い出すと、glibcの中の１万以上あるファイルの個々のライセンスはGPLv2だったりLGPLv2だったりGPLv3だったりごちゃ混ぜですけどね。

Answer (score 2):

**LGPL2.1 の対象であるならば、第 6 節の規定に従わなければならない**でしょう。

LGPL2.1 のライブラリ「だけ」を使うかどうかということは関係がなく、第 5 節の規定によって、対象外かどうかが決まってくると思います。「だけ」を使っていても、第 5 節の規定により、対象外となる場合は、第 6 節の規定に従う必要はないわけです。

> Mozila/FireFox も LibraOffice も、そのライセンス一覧に glibc がありません。

Firefox も LibreOffice も **LGPL2.1 の適用対象外である**（と作者が判断している）ものだからでしょう。

本当のところは、Mozilla Foundation や、The Document Foundation に尋ねてもらうほかありません。

> glibc だけ、何か特別なライセンスになっているのでしょうか？

我々第三者が、このような場で、1) 勝手に（Firefox/LibreOffice は LGPL2.1 対象であると）判断して、その勝手な判断を元に、2) なのに LGPL2.1（の第 6 節の規定）に反している、これはどういうこと？……と続けても、回答する側も結局は「意見」しか述べられないことになります。

この点に関する私の「意見」としては「そもそもLGPL2.1の適用対象外ということじゃないか」というものになります。

常識的に考えても、Firefox/LibreOffice が glibc の**派生著作物**に該当するとは考えにくいと思うのですが……。glibc に、Web を閲覧して HTML や JavaScript をパースして実行する能力があるわけではないでしょうし、ワープロや表計算能力を持っているわけでもありませんよね。

Answer (score 1):

glibc は LGPL です。過去にはエプソンコーワの LGPL 違反が問題になりました。
http://srad.jp/submission/7793/

Comment: エプソンコーワの件はリバースエンジニアリング周りの条項が問題だったようですが、この質問で挙げられている著作権表示はどうだったんでしょうね…。 http://web.archive.org/web/20030623161822/http://www.epkowa.co.jp/linux/DLinfo.html